# File object with white space in directory name

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to list the number of files in a directory. But I am unable to get so and I suspect it has got to do with the white space in the parent directory names.
What I am doing is in a .properties file I set the value as -

```
dir.loc=H:/Main/dir one/dir - two/dir3/dir four  
dir.name=Run
```

Now in a jave file I set these values to String variables as -

```
String s1 = properties.getProperty("dir.loc");
String s2 = properties.getProperty("dir.name");
```

I create a File object as -

```
File f = new File(s1, s2);
File[] fList = f.listFiles();
```

Now here the `fList` is `null`;
The H drive is on another remote machine and I reckon the java program tries to locate the 'Run' directory locally rather than finding it on H drive and because it does not find 'Run' the list return `null`.

When I tried in a simple java class as -

```
File f = new File("H:/Main/dir one/dir - two/dir3/dir four", "Run");
```

then I do get the result with `f.listFiles().length;`

So I guess it might have to do something with extracting the value from properties file and assigning it to a String variable.

Am I correct in my assumption?
What could be possible solution to this problem?

Comment: How do you load properties and what is the value of `new File(s1, s2).getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: This is what gets prints for `getAbsolutePath()` as 'H:\Main\dir one\dir - two\dir3\dir four\Run'   and I am loading the properties file simply as - `properties.load(Thread.currentThread).getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Test.properties"));`

Comment: well, it seems no different than in your "direct" example then, what is weird. Re-check your access permissions on drive "H"; also, you may try setting UNC path (in form of `\\machine\share\target`).

Comment: @barti_ddu Was able to get it resolved, have posted my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution for my problem, quite simple actually.
I did the following -

In properties file -

```
dir.loc=H:/Main/dir one/dir - two/dir3/dir four/Run
```

In a config java file -

```
String s1 = properties.getProperty("dir.loc");
```

In my java program -

```
File tempF = new File(s1);
File dirLoc = new File(tempF.getAbsolutePath());
```

`dirLoc.listFiles().length;` gives out a number.

The comment by @barti_ddu about getAbsolutePath() got me into bit of thinking about may be using that.
Is anything wrong with this solution or is not quite a decent one?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. Values are screwed up when reading them from the properties file. 
Do this instead:

```
dir.loc="H:/Main/dir one/dir - two/dir3/dir four"
```

Comment: Sorry, doesnt work. I am trying various ways around this viz. with escape char etc, no success yet. But when I am using the " as you suggested and then when I sysout `f.getName()`, the result is `Run"`

Comment: @Swift-Tuttle not sure I understand your comment, what do you mean by "did not work"? If you do a `System.out.println(dir.loc)` does it display the correct  value?

Comment: Well, if I sysout `dir.loc` the o/p is `"H:/Main/dir one/dir - two/dir3/dir four"`. So for creating the file object I pass the String variable containing this as the first argument and the String variable containing containing Run. Then the `getAbsolutePath()` comes as `c:\Program Files\eclipse\"H:\Main\dir one\dir - two\dir3\dir four"\Run` and `getName()` as Run

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply need to trim the value of your properties.
In the code you have shown, the

```
  dir.loc=H:/Main/dir one/dir - two/dir3/dir four
```

has trailing spaces.

Does this:

```
String s1 = properties.getProperty("dir.loc").trim();
String s2 = properties.getProperty("dir.name").trim();
```

fix it?

Comment: Very sorry, its just a typo here but the actual value doesnt contain any trailing spaces.